# MS Outlook - keyboard shortcut to move to unread folder?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

Would anyone know the keyboard shortcut to move control to the unread folder? This is the only operation for which i need to use mouse. Checking the Navigation Pane, it isn't actually a physical folder but a kind of filter.

Or any workaround/config to do for the same?

[image: Unread folder]

Answer (score 1):

"Unread Mail" is a search folder. To mark selected messages as unread, just press **Ctrl+U**.

Comment: I want to move to that folder. Move as in move the control or display the unread items. I am not talking of moving a item to that folder.

Comment: No way to move to any search folder (including Unread Mail). Search folders are virtual folders: they only shows items found in physical folders by some search criteria. In this case, you just need to mark messages as unread. Or create a separate folder in Outlook and move unread items there.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same.
Figured out a way.
I added the "filter unread" and "filter sent to me" options to the quick access tool bar.
These were in HOME -> Find section -> Filter Email -> Right click and add to quick

From there,
I use ALT then whichever number they are at.
So now, I can (without touching the mouse) navidate from "ALL" and "UNREAD".

Cheers!